# Mostrar elementos mientras se tipea en el buscador en django con ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

En http://hechizos.herokuapp.com/ esta un buscador que muestra unos resultados mientras se tipea en él. Pero ahora lo que quiero es que no muestre esos resultados si no que me vaya cambiando la lista de hechizos mientras estoy tipeando allí. Algo así como lo que hace google creo que me va mostrando resultados diferentes mientras escribo.

el codigo del buscador con ajax

```
    <!-- RESULTADO CON AJAX -->
    <script>
        $('#busqueda').keyup(function(e){
            $("#resultados").text("");
            consulta = $("#busqueda").val();
             $.ajax({
             data: {'name': consulta},
             url: '{% url 'Spell:spell_search' %}',
             type: 'get',
             success : function(data) {    
                    $("#resultados").text("");                  
                    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                        if((i % 2)==0)
                            $("#resultados").append("<a class=\"Search-resultados--item \" href=/"+data[i].slug+">"+data[i].name+"</a>");
                        else
                            $("#resultados").append("<a class=\"Search-resultados--item Search-resultados--info\" href=/"+data[i].slug+">"+data[i].name+"</a>");
                    }
                    if(consulta == ""){$("#resultados").text("");}
             },
             error : function(message) {
                     $("#resultados").text("");
                  }
             });
        });
    </script>
</section>
```

views.py

```
class SpellListView(ListView):
    model = Spell
    template_name = 'spells/spell_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'spells'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SpellListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context


class SpellSearchView(View):
    model = Spell

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            spells = self.model.objects.filter(name__icontains = request.GET['name']).values('id', 'name', 'slug')[:10]
            return JsonResponse(list(spells), safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Solo se permiten consultas mediante AJAX", safe=False)

class SpellDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Spell
    template_name = 'spells/spell_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'
    context_object_name = 'spell'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SpellDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context

class SpellCategoryListView(SpellListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, id = self.args[0])
        ranges = Range.objects.filter(group = group)
        queryset = self.model.objects.filter(range__in = ranges)
        return queryset

class SpellEditView(UpdateView):
    model = Spell
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'range', 'type', 'method', 'object',]
    template_name_suffix = '_update'
    success_url = '../'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SpellEditView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Creo que una manera sería crear una vista y colocar ahí los resultados filtrandolos por lo que contiene el buscador, pero no estoy muy seguro.

Si pueden ayudarme con eso lo agradeciría. Si necesitan algún código extra, diganlo :P

Comment: Creo que no vas mal encaminado. Tendrás que hacer que Django reciba las peticiones AJAX a través de un View específico para esta tarea. Deberías hacerlo a través de un método POST y llamar al View por Javascript "onChange()" por así decirlo. Te sugiero [seguir estas recomendaciones](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) a la hora de montarlo todo. Sobretodo recuerda añadir el csrf_token.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es cada vez que la persona escribe hacer un llamado a un endpoint que retorne un json con la información del los hechiceros, luego con jquery limpiar el div donde guardas las información y generar la nueva información de los hechiceros.